# RIPS: Code is object-oriented. This is not supported yet and can lead to false negatives

Tags: php, security

I want to do static code analysis of a web application containing php code and I have chosen 
[RIPS](http://rips-scanner.sourceforge.net/) static code analyzer tool.

When I started scanning the source code which I think contains object oriented code, I am getting an info message as
 "Code is object-oriented. This is not supported yet and can lead to false negatives."

Shall I proceed with the findings of the RIPS? How can I do static code analysis of object oriented php code with the RIPS? Is there any other tool better than RIPS?

Thanks

Comment: It looks like RIPS is doing taint tracking. I would *guess* that it simply discards any data flows that go through an object, in which case you could still in principle get some useful findings from dataflow paths that never touched an object. (If it treats all data read from objects as tainted, on the other hand, you'll be swamped with false positives. Well, more swamped than you normally are from static code analysis tools...)

Comment: [False negative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_I_and_type_II_errors#False_negative_error) means that something may not be detected although it should be detected. So due to the missing support for object-oriented code, vulnerabilities in that object-oriented code probably won’t be reported correctly. However, static code should not be affected by this.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Can you suggest some better static code analyzer for php?

Comment: Think you might need to go with a commercial offering like HP Fortify or Checkmarx